# Can we replace urlopen in this code with requests library?

Tags: concurrency, python-requests, concurrent.futures

Can we replace urlopen library in this example for concurrent requests with the requests library in python 2.7?

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Your code seems to do a simple HTTP get with timeout, so the equivalent with requests is:

```python
import requests

def load_url(url, timeout):
    r = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
    return r.content
```